# Stata: Storing only part of a FE regression output for graphing

Tags: stata

I am running a regression with two fixed effects categories (country and year, is economic macro data). Since I am using `xtreg`, one is autohid, but the other is a variable:

```
xtreg fiveyearyg taxratio i.year if taxratiocut == 1,  i(wbcode1) fe cluster(wbcode1)
estimates store yi
```

I am running a number of these and I want to graph the coefficients for `taxratio` from each. But when I store the data, it stores both the `taxratio` coefficient, and the 50+ coefficients for the `year` fixed effects.

After a lot of searching, I cannot find any way to store (or recall) just part of the regression output, the one coefficient (with SEs) that I care about. Does anyone know a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessing coefficients is as easy as calling `_b[varname]`; analogously the corresponding standard errors: `_se[varname]`.

An example:

```
webuse grunfeld, clear

qui xtreg mvalue invest i.year,fe cluster(company)

// coef for invest
display _b[invest]

// std error for invest
display _se[invest]

// displayed results in matrix
matrix list r(table)
```

For multiple-equation models use `[eqno]_b[varname]` where the preceding bracket contains an equation number.

More detail can be found in [[U] 13.5 Accessing coefficients and standard errors](http://www.stata.com/manuals14/u13.pdf).

Starting Stata 12, estimation commands also store results in **r()** [and not just **e()**]. Notice I listed `r(table)`, which contains most results displayed by the estimation command `xtreg`.

You show interest in plotting coefficients, so you should read on the user-written command `coefplot`. Run `ssc install coefplot` to download and `help coefplot` to get started. It has many options.

### Edit

A complete example that plots only coefficients for `invest` (leaving out those for `year`), using `coefplot`, and based on conditional regressions is:

```
clear
set more off

webuse grunfeld

xtreg mvalue invest i.year if time <= 10,fe cluster(company)
estimates store before10

xtreg mvalue invest i.year if time > 10,fe cluster(company)
estimates store after10 

coefplot before10 after10, keep(invest)
```

Comment: Oh, this is very helpful, thank you! Just to ask (if its not a bother), for graphing i was hoping to use coefplot to set up a number of coefficients with the ci intervals around them on a graph. ive used coefplot to call up the data that is stored, but here the year data would still of course be stored.

Do you know, once you can call the numbers (and maybe create variables for them) how i would graph them with the ci on coefplot, or perhaps something else?

Edit: Yeah, my plan was to use coefplot, i guess i am confused on how to move from using data beyond "estimates store"

Comment: Sorry, but your question is not clear to me. If you're interested in plotting only the coefficient for variable `invest`, you can use the `keep()` or `drop()` options available in `coefplot`.

Comment: The `help` file has examples and points to a [document](https://ideas.repec.org/p/bss/wpaper/1.html) for even more. Take time to go over the `help` and the document, find plots similar to those you want to produce, make serious attempts with your data, and come back and post a question if you run into problems. Remember a good question has [reproducible code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hm, ok, so lets say after i run my regression, i say `estimates store A`. ive used `coefplot` to graph say `coefplot A B C` from 3 regressions, but right now those have 50+ year fe variables in them. Could i say something like `drop(all) keep(myvariable)` to just have the one that i want?

EDiT: Ok, i will try to do that. i generally have a lot of problems understanding the help documentation, i am not familiar enough with the vocabulary used, so i was hoping if my question was easy it could save me a few hours. Hopefully i will have a moment of clarity!

Comment: Then try `coefplot A B C, keep(invest)`. Again, the recommendation is to read the documentation to which I've pointed.

Comment: See also [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) on how to vote/accept answers once you receive one. This is the Stack Overflow way of "closing" the thread.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do that:

```
webuse grunfeld,clear
qui xtreg mvalue invest i.year,fe cluster(company)
```

//`e(b)` stores coefficient matrix and `e(V)` stores variance-covariance matrix. For details type: `ereturn list` after running the model

//let's say you want to extract only the coefficient on invest

```
mat coef_matrix=e(b)
scalar coef_invest=coef_matrix[1,1]
dis coef_invest 
1.7178414
```

//to extract se of the the coefficient on invest

```
mat var_matrix=e(V)
mat diag_var_matrix=vecdiag(var_matrix) //diagonal elements are variances and the standard errors are square roots of these variances
matmap diag_var_matrix se_matrix , m(sqrt(@))) //you need to install matmap using ssc install matmap, you will get error if variance is negative
scalar se_invest=se_matrix[1,1] 
dis se_invest
.14082153
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! When trying to run this command on my own data, for the SE i get an error when i try to display se invest, "type mismatch". i looked through the display documentation, but couldnt figure out why this scalar would not display, when the other would. Maybe you have an answer to that?